# Re-request with next.haldle not working in Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs-observables

Here is my code below...the problem is after the token is expired(401) the api for getting refresh token get hit, but the request is not re-sent with the inner next.handle().

```
export class InterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {

    isRefreshingToken = false;
    isUserLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.pipe(select(isLoggedIn));

    constructor(public auth: AuthService, private store: Store<AppState>,http: HttpClient) {}

    private addTokenHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token})}`
            }
        });
        return request;
    }

    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(environment.authTokenKey)}`
            }
        });

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap(
                event => {
                     if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    if(error.status === 401 && !this.isRefreshingToken && this.isUserLoggedIn$) {
                        this.isRefreshingToken = true;
                        this.auth.getRefreshToken().subscribe( (authToken: IAuthToken) =>
                            {
                                this.store.dispatch(new TokenSet({authToken}));
                                let newReq = this.addTokenHeader(request, authToken.token);
                                return next.handle(newReq);
                            }
                            
                        );  
                            
                    }
                    else {
                        this.isRefreshingToken = false;
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The result I got is:
[image]

But I want a re-sent of role api after refreshToken api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iyktci?file=src/app/interceptors/jwt.auth.interceptor.ts) example which is fully working on my application at the moment.

You're missing the code which re-submits the failed request.